# Inno setup--Compile time Checking like "Check" functionality in Runtime

Tags: inno-setup

I have a requirement like following.

Based on `AppName` in Script, will include Files that listed in [File] Section   in Installer.

I mention two files in Script like,

`[Files]
Source: "XYZ.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: isInclude;
Source: "ABCC.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: isInclude;`

Let Assume,
 If `AppName='Hi'` then only include only `XYZ.txt`  file in installer.
 If `AppName='Hello'`, then only `ABC.txt` file include into installer.

I wrote code in [Code] section

```
[Code]
Function isInclude(): Boolean;
 var VALUE1 : String;
 var VALUE2 : String;
 var RESULT : Longint;

Begin
   VALUE1 := ExpandConstant('{MyAppName}');
   VALUE2 := 'Hi';
   RESULT :=CompareText(VALUE1 ,VALUE2 );

If RESULT=0 then
  Begin
    Result := True;
  End
Else 
  Result := False;
End;
```

But it's not working...How can we do this?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Preprocessor defines cannot be expanded by `ExpandConstant` function. That seems to be a common mistake. They are inlined in the script before it's compiled. So its usage is pointless. Then, if you strip out the rest and keep just `VALUE1 := '{MyAppName}';` you'll be looking at an ordinary string value with no relation to a define. So, what you are missing is the sharp char. Use `VALUE1 := '{#MyAppName}';` and you should be fine. The preprocessor will then replace `{#MyAppName}` with the actual value of the define.

Comment: One advice when I see you working with preprocessor. You can let the preprocessor save the preprocessed script into file if you add a line like `#expr SaveToFile("C:\PreprocessedScript.iss")` at the very end of the script. In that file you will see what is passed to the compiler.

Comment: Thanks for Reply @TLama. I'. sorry, i didn't understand. Please tell me `"Is it  possible,  include only specific files (not all files specified in [File] section) when compile?"`

Comment: Yes, [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/QJwiTXFY), e.g. Your attempt was for runtime, not for compilation time and I didn't pay enough attention to the text. My fault.

Comment: Thanks @TLama; My intention was in Compile time only. I also worked in Runtime checking by using "Check" feature. Yes, i too not focus on , Function works in Runtime , not compile time. Thanks for helping...:)